# How do you invert scipy quad function to pass in an arc length and receive a value for (t)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, calculus, quad

If I were to run something like the code below where I pass in the minor and major arc of an ellipse as 3.05 and 2.23 with the 50 degree angle formed by the arc, how would I be able to take the output of 2.531432761012828 as the arc length and pass it back through to solve for t? Thanks!

```
import math
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
t = math.atan(3.05*math.tan(5*math.pi/18)/2.23)
Dx = lambda t: -3.05 * np.sin(t)   
Dy = lambda t: 2.23 * np.cos(t)
quad(lambda t: np.sqrt(Dx(t)**2 + Dy(t)**2), 0, t)
```

The output of the last one was: (2.531432761012828, 2.810454936566873e-14)

Comment: Have you tried `full_output`?  With analytical integration, can you 'backout' the upper integration limit from the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the upper limit of integration, given the value of the integral, one can apply [fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) to the function which calculates that integral for variable upper limits. Example (not repeating the lines you already have):

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
target = 2.531432761012828
fun = lambda s: quad(lambda t: np.sqrt(Dx(t)**2 + Dy(t)**2), 0, s)[0] - target
s0 = fsolve(fun, 0)[0]
print(s0)
```

This prints `1.02051`.

I dislike having both the variable of integration and the upper limit denoted by the same letter, so in my code the upper limit is called `s`.

Comment: In a crude sense the tries various upper limit values in the vicinity of your initial guess until it finds one that produces the same integral.  It's more sophisticated than a hunt-n-peck, but the principal is the same.  Try values until you get a match.